# gatling graph up - constant - down

Tags: gatling

I create a scenario gatling Charge test

```
rampUserPerSec(rate: 0).to(10 * 3).during(Duration.OfSecond(360))
constantUsersPerSec(rate: 10 * 3 ).during((Duration.OfSecond(720))
rampUsersPerSec(rate: 10 * 3).to(0).during((Duration.OfSecond(360))
```

. But I don't get what I want ie a rise, a straight line for the constant is a descent.I would like to do as in the picture. thank you for help[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you problem is. What do you currently have and how doesn't it not meet your expectations?

Comment: @stéphane LANDELLE I can't keep a rise in load without such a dip for the constant